# Export Html to PDF using ITextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext, html-to-pdf

I have tried the code below, I am also facing an error. I am using latest DLL.

```
String strSelectUserListBuilder = @"<html><body>
                                <h1>My First Heading</h1>
                                <p>My first paragraph.</p>
                            </body>
                        </html>";

String htmlText = strSelectUserListBuilder.ToString();

List<IElement> htmlarraylist = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), null);
```

I got this error:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: HTMLWorker is deprecated and not supported anymore. Since you use the latest version, you'll find its replacement, XMLWorker.

Comment: on which line you are getting error?

Comment: @QaisarShabbirAwan Have you figured out how to place images on the PDF? Maybe try a full `<image/>` or `<img/>`?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\MySamplePDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = 
             new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));
document.Close();
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what is with the PdfWriter.GetInstance call that does nothing with the returned value?

Is there some side effect on the document that is passed to it?

Comment: hi @Kapil Khandelwal! this works fine but if i add image and html <table> this wont work it gives error...! any solution ?

Answer (score -1):

lets try below code it will help you convert HTML to PDF file.

```
String strSelectUserListBuilder = @"<html><body>
                                <h1>My First Heading</h1>
                                <p>My first paragraph.</p>
                            </body>
                        </html>";

String htmlText = strSelectUserListBuilder.ToString();
CreatePDFFromHTMLFile(htmlText , pdfFileName);


public void CreatePDFFromHTMLFile(string HtmlStream, string FileName)
 {
     try
     {
         object TargetFile = FileName;
         string ModifiedFileName = string.Empty;
         string FinalFileName = string.Empty;

         /* To add a Password to PDF -test */
         TestPDF.HtmlToPdfBuilder builder = new TestPDF.HtmlToPdfBuilder(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
         TestPDF.HtmlPdfPage first = builder.AddPage();
         first.AppendHtml(HtmlStream);
         byte[] file = builder.RenderPdf();
         File.WriteAllBytes(TargetFile.ToString(), file);

         iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(TargetFile.ToString());
         ModifiedFileName = TargetFile.ToString();
         ModifiedFileName = ModifiedFileName.Insert(ModifiedFileName.Length - 4, "1");

         string password = "password";
         iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, new FileStream(ModifiedFileName, FileMode.Append), iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS, password, "", iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);ss
         reader.Close();
         if (File.Exists(TargetFile.ToString()))
             File.Delete(TargetFile.ToString());
         FinalFileName = ModifiedFileName.Remove(ModifiedFileName.Length - 5, 1);
         File.Copy(ModifiedFileName, FinalFileName);
         if (File.Exists(ModifiedFileName))
             File.Delete(ModifiedFileName);

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
 }
```

Comment: but it wont parse the HTML Image tag markups. do you know how to parse images? & what is the TestPDF ?