# How to convert HTML into PDF using iTextSharp in winform?

Tags: c#, html, winforms, pdf, itext

I want to convert HTML into PDF in windows form. I have come across many fabulous articles online such as these:

- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Categories/iTextSharp.aspx
- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-HTML-DIV-contents-to-PDF-using-iTextSharp-in-ASPNet.aspx
- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASP.Net-GridView-to-PDF-with-Custom-Columns-Widths-using-iTextSharp.aspx

But they do not quite address my problem.

Is it possible that I can just pass a string of HTML and convert it into PDF in Winform?

For example :

```
string html = "<table><tr><td>Arbaaz</td><tr></table>"
```

Can I just pass this string to some iText method to create PDF?

Comment: i didb't get your point... whether you want create pdf with html tags like <h1>Hi</h1> or just you want print only 'Hi' even you has pass with tags

Comment: I dont want to print <h1><b>Hi<b></h1> I want to print Hi in bold as it would appear on a webpage.

Comment: It is easy to format in html.

Comment: What you are looking for is called XMLWorker, you'll find more information at https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp.xmlworker/ and http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer I was looking for here ..

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\MySamplePDF.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker hw = 
             new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(document);
hw.Parse(new StringReader(htmlText));
document.Close();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378661/2064292